# Simple app showing front camera video feed not working in Cordova Android

Tags: android, cordova

I have done some research in different sites but I have not seen an answer that works. Maybe this [github issue](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-camera/issues/486) might be leading to where I want. I have been trying to make a simple android app that when opened, it shows the front or back camera (it shouldn't matter) output (video). I do not have a lot of experience with cordova nor android apps in general.

To recreate this:

```
cordova create my-camera-app com.example.mycameraapp MyCameraApp
cd my-camera-app
cordova platform add android
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-camera
```

And now in `www/index.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>My Camera App</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <video id="videoElement"></video>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

and `www/js/app.js`:

```
document.addEventListener('deviceready', onDeviceReady, false);

function onDeviceReady() {
  // Get the video element
  var videoElement = document.getElementById('videoElement');

  // Set the source of the video to the device's front camera
  navigator.camera.getPicture(
    function successCallback(imageData) {
      videoElement.src = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageData;
      videoElement.play();
    },
    function errorCallback(error) {
      alert('Unable to get the camera: ' + error);
    },
    {
      quality: 50,
      destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
      sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA,
      cameraDirection: Camera.Direction.FRONT
    }
  );
}
```

Finally adding to the `config.xml` file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="true" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.front" android:required="true" />
```

And running with the device connected to the pc: `cordova run android`

As you can see, it's nothing fancy as I just want to have the baseline working before doing anything else. But it is not working. I just get the symbol of the videoplayer in the app, but nothing else is happening nor can I press anything. I have tried in two different android devices (Lenovo tablet and Samsung phone), as I saw in my research that compatibility with the device can be the issue sometimes.

In case you also want to see the complete `config.xml` file:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="com.example.mycameraapp" version="1.0.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/n>
  <name>My Camera App</name>
  <description>A simple app that displays the front camera video stream</descri>
  <author email="youremail@example.com" href="http://example.com/">Your Name</a>
  <content src="index.html" />
  <access origin="*" />
  <platform name="android">
    <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="21" />
    <preference name="android-targetSdkVersion" value="31" />
    <preference name="android-build-tool" value="29.0.2" />
    <preference name="android-enableHybridWebView" value="true" />
    <preference name="android-useLegacyWhitelist" value="true" />
    <allow-intent href="market:*" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.front" />
  </platform>
</widget>
```

Comment: Why are you trying to add an image as source of a video element ? Are you trying to display the video feed of the camera in your video element ?

Comment: Yes! That is exactly what I am trying to do. Sorry, I will edit a little the question to make that clear @Eric

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally managed to solve this. It might be smart to check the `platforms/android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml` file and add

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
```

But I am not sure if it's necessary. Code that worked, thanks to [@Eric's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76043915/7396613), I was able to search in a specific direction.

I do everything in the `index.html` file:

```
let constraintObj = {
      audio: false,
      video: {
        facingMode: "user",
        width: { min: 640, ideal: 1280, max: 1920 },
        height: { min: 480, ideal: 720, max: 1080 },
      },
    };

    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraintObj)
      .then(function (mediaStreamObj) {
        let video = document.getElementById('video');
        video.srcObject = mediaStreamObj;

        video.onloadedmetadata = function (ev) {
          video.play();
        };
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.error('Camera error: ' + error);
      });
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot display the camera feed with taking a picture and stuffing it to the video element. It's not as straight forward as you think it is. If you are trying to display the video feed, you need to use

```
 navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia
```

Then convert the stream into a `MediaStream` and add `MediaStreamTrack` to the `MediaStream` then link the tracks/stream to the video element.

Check out https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaStream

Comment: Thanks to your answer I managed to solve this. Thank you very much!